# How do I prevent plates coming out of the dishwasher squeaky?

Tags: cleaning

Over time it seems my dishwasher and tablets (normally [Finish](http://www.finishinfo.com.au/)) have taken the surface off my plates and bowls, and now they have an unpleasant squeaky, nails-on-a-blackboard feel. I use Rinse Aid (also Finish branded).

What causes this, and can it be prevented? Are certain kinds of plates more susceptible than others, or is quality a factor? Should I be using dishwashing powders or liquids instead? For what it's worth, cutlery, glasses, pots and pans etc. seem to be fine.

There's a related question on physics.se [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148953/why-are-dishwasher-washed-glasses-squeaky-clean) but it seems to suggest that modern dishwashing chemicals should have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may be that your plates and bowls are unfortunately permanently damaged. It really depends on what kind of material they were made out of.

I personally like using all-in-one gels with no rinse aide. The rinse aide simply prevents spotting on finished dishware, so isn't necessary to have clean dishes. If it isn't a big deal, skip the rinse aide and just try a gel or single-use pack. If they still have water spots, as soon as the dishwasher cools down a little, dry your dishes by hand and you won't have to use a rinse-aide.

The less chemicals touching your dishware (especially the delicate stuff) the better.

Comment: Yeah I suspect they're permanently damaged, I was hoping to prevent it happening next time - maybe I'll try the liquids. Cheers :)

Comment: Newbie - how can they be 'all-in-one with no rinse aide', I thought that's what the ALL meant?

Comment: You would think so, right? Sorry I wasn't specific enough for you to understand. Usually rinse aides are not included in gel-packs since they are not utilized during the rinse cycle. Rinse aides usually have a separate chamber which you fill apart from the detergent chamber.